# mapping entity cannot be done cause it cannot find propety

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have Page entity with properties Keyword and Keywords.

`Keyword` property store one string like `string Keyword = "my awesome page, page";`

Keyword will store this information inside database.

Keywords on the other hand retrieve this keyword content and separating with commas.

so I have inside my model

```
public Page : Entity<int>
{
   public virtual string Keyword {get; set;}
   public virtual IList<string> Keywords 
   {
       get { return Keyword.Split(','); }
       set { Keyword = string.Join(",", value); }
   }
   public Page() { Keywords = new List<string>(); }
}
```

so I tried to map this entity with conformist mapping by code

```
public class PageMap : ClassMapping<Page>
{
    public PageMap()
    {
       Property(x => x.Keyword);
       Property(x => x.Keywords, m =>
            { 
                m.Access(Accessor.Field);                    
       });
    }
}
```

but I'm getting expcetion like

> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document:
>   mapping_by_code   ----> NHibernate.MappingException : Problem trying
>   to set property type by reflection
>   NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException : Could not find property nor
>   field 'Keywords' in class 'Model.Page'

Even I understand message that property cannot be found I do not understand why? and how to overcome this.

thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are defining the access to the Keywords property to be by field but you do not have a field defined for the Keywords Property. NHibernate is looking for a field called _keywords more than likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. First, the Keywords property is "virtual", meaning that it is not persisted, it is calculated/built in runtime. To make it working you do not need to map and therefore to store it. Just remove the Keywords mapping...

The Second thing is the mapping. In case, that `Keywords` won't be virtual *(runtime resolved based ont the `Keyword` property value)*, we have to map it as collection. Any collection (e.g. `IList<string>`) represents one-to-many relation, (in fluent called HasMany):

```
<bag name="Keywords" table="Keywords">
  <key column="PageId" />
  <element column="Keyword" />
</bag>
```

This will store all keywords in its own table (e.g. *Keywords*), referenced by `PageId` column and persisted in a column *(e.g. `nvrachar`)* called `Keyword`. The Fluent syntax would be like:

```
HasMany(x => x.Keywords)
    .Table("Keywords")
    .KeyColumn("PageId")
    .Element("Keyword");
```

But, as already said: if the `Keywords` is virutal, do not map it.

Comment: All my properties in domain class are virtual, in nhibernate properties are virtual to trigger lazy loading. If I understand you correctly you suggest that I introduce new object in this case component (from ddd perspective)?

Comment: No, *(I thought that `virtual` word won't be working;)*. I mean virtual from perspective: not existing in DB. This property is resolved from the value of the `Keyword` property. It has NO column related in DB. It is virtual/artificial/not-persisted. So we DO not need to map it. Anyhow. We just will be provided with value in Keyword property (loaded by NHibernate) and return its data in different way (as an array) when accessing the Keywords. So, just skip its mapping and it should be ok. Or use different table for persisting more values in more rows.In that case HasMany is the correct mapping